# Paired Probability Predictions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am working on a classification problem where I my machine learning model generate probabilities on two given inputs. One of this inputs will always have a ground truth of being positive and the other negative, the order is unknown. My prediction should be whether the first input is positive or negative.

I am trying to figure out if my model gives a prediction probability of >0.9 that the first input is positive and a prediction probability of >0.9 that the second input is negative, or vice-versa, than what is the the total probability of my prediction being correct for the first input?

Comment: What’s the difference if you make predictions for the second input? To me, you seem to have a binary problem.